# Recreating ZLIB from scratch

Tags: zlib, deflate

I am trying to understand how do the `ZLIB` algorithm that was implemented in python works, I understand that it uses a variant of `DEFLATE`. I am wondering if it is possible to do it by hand from the given `Data` to the `Compress Data`.

```
Data :                      00   Compress Data :                63 00 00     bin:   01100011 00000000 00000000
Data :                      01   Compress Data :                63 04 00     bin:   01100011 00000100 00000000
Data :                      02   Compress Data :                63 02 00     bin:   01100011 00000010 00000000
Data :                      03   Compress Data :                63 06 00     bin:   01100011 00000110 00000000
Data :                      04   Compress Data :                63 01 00     bin:   01100011 00000001 00000000
```

The above data is compressed with `ZLIB` level 1 compression with the header `78 01` and their `ADLER32` stripped. So what is left is the compress data from `DEFLATE` (if I am not wrong)

Numbering the bits as such,

```
+--------+
|76543210|
+--------+
```

and the bytes as follow,

```
    0        1
+--------+--------+
|00001000|00000010|
+--------+--------+
```

From `DEFLATE` standard [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1951).

I understand that bit `0` from the first byte indicates the last block of the file and bit `1` and `2` indicates that `DEFLATE` is using mode `10` compression. But I am unable to recover/understand what do the rest of the bits means or how to compute them by hand.

Below is an extended version of the bytes,

```
Data :      01 01 01 01 02 02    Compress Data :    63 64 64 64 64 62 02 00      bin:   01100011 01100100 01100100 01100100 01100100 01100010 00000010 00000000
```

Answer (score 0):

zlib does not use a "variant" of DEFLATE. It uses DEFLATE.

The DEFLATE compressed data format is fully described in [RFC 1951](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1951).

You can use [infgen](https://github.com/madler/infgen) to disassemble DEFLATE streams. Example output for your first one:

```
! infgen 2.4 output
!
last
fixed
literal 0
end
```

It says that the first block is also the last block, that it is a fixed-code block, and that there is a literal zero byte as the data contained in the block.

You can also look at the source code for infgen to assist in your understanding of RFC 1951.